# unresolved identifier in swift 3

Tags: uibutton, swift3

My code is trying to download some JSON data and save it to an array, then loop through the array and create a button for each item.  I am having trouble assigning my function to the buttons for giving them functionality.  Here is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //connect to website
    let SongArray: Array<Any>
    let url = URL(string:"*******")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil
        {
            print("error")
        }
        else
        {
            if let content = data
            {
                do
                {
                    //download JSON data from php page, display data
                    let SongArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [[String]]
                    print(SongArray)

                    //Make buttons with JSON array
                    var buttonY:  CGFloat = 20
                    for song in SongArray {
                        let SongButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: buttonY, width: 250, height: 30))
                        buttonY = buttonY + 50 // 50px spacing

                        SongButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10  //Edge formatting for buttons

                        SongButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray //Color for buttons

                        SongButton.setTitle("\(song[0])", for: UIControlState.normal) //button title

                        SongButton.titleLabel?.text = "\(song[0])"

                        SongButton.addTarget(self,action: #selector(songButtonPressed(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)  //button press / response

                        self.view.addSubview(SongButton)  // adds buttons to view
                    }
                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()

}

 } //close viewDidLoad

 func songButtonPressed(_sender:UIButton!) { // function for buttons

if sender.titleLabel?.text == "\("Song[0]")" {
    print("So far so good!!")
}
 }
```

I am getting an error on the line with SongButton.addTarget...

the error says 'Use of Unresolved Identifier "SongButtonPressed"'  even though its declared right after the viewDidLoad function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you declared the selector `SongButtonPressed(_:)` it's (note the underscore)

```
func SongButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) { // no implicit unwrapped optional !!
```

By the way the proper selector syntax is `#selector(SongButtonPressed(_:))`

Two notes:

- `.mutableContainers` has no effect in Swift at all. Omit the parameter. And delete the line `let SongArray: Array<Any>`. You should get an *unused* warning.
- Functions, methods and variables are supposed to start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: I am more focused on the functionality before making small changes like that don't effect my code at all.  I made all changes you said in this post.  The error is still there at at the same place.

Comment: I see, use `#selector(SongButtonPressed(_:))` I updated the answer.

Comment: Your updated code does not consider the underscore character in the `func` and once again: **No implicit unwrapped optional** as the `sender` parameter.

Comment: I did that in actually, its just not on the website.  I'll add that.  the error is still there.

Comment: Consider also the space character after the underscore `_ sender`

Comment: thanks, the same line has a new error now though, it says "Argument of '#selector' cannot refer to global function 'songButtonPressed'.  progress at least

Comment: Make sure that `songButtonPressed` is in the class scope (inside the class)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that.. could you please show me?

Comment: The function `songButtonPressed` must be inside the braces of the class declaration: `class xyz { ...  func songButtonPressed ...   }`

Comment: that made the error go away, thank you very much. I also needed to add .self to this line:

Comment: SongButton.addTarget(self,action: #selector(self.songButtonPressed(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

Comment: Right, it's inside a closure